# Calling a service from one controller updates scope variable of another controller automatically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

can anyone please help me here.

https://plnkr.co/edit/vrHzXAelRlPKUrjfkYgw

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="studentModule">
    <div ng-controller="boyCtrl">
        Boy: <input type="text" ng-model="name" > <br/>
        Add: <input type="button" value="add" ng-click="addBoy();" >
            {{name}}
    </div>

    <br/>

    <div ng-controller="girlCtrl">
        Girl: <input type="text" ng-model="name" /> <br/>
        Add: <input type="button" value="add" ng-click="addGirl();" >
            {{name}}
    </div>
    <br/>

    <div ng-controller="displayCtrl">
        Display list <input type="button" value="display" ng-
 click="getStudents()">
        <table>
            <tr>
               <th>name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="student in students  track by $index">
               <td>{{student}}</td>
             </tr>
         </table>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Steps:

1- Add a name in the boy textbox.

2- click on add button against boy.

3- Click on display button, the name is displayed.

4- Add another name in the boy textbox.

5- click on add button.

Issue: the name displays in the table even though display button is not clicked.

Comment: When you do you want the `{{name}}` to be displayed, since you have bound the variable to input box, its showing dynamically!

Answer (score 0):

since angular support two way binding its bind the service values to the array. To prevent that use `angular.copy`

```
$scope.getStudents = function() {
    $scope.students = angular.copy(studentService.displayStudents())
};
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/KfieEW7A04rxzjKKuZWE?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Sachila, though the solution you gave is perfect. Just have a question, how the "students" variable is attached to a function that returns an array.

Comment: since angular support 2-way binding, service variables and scope arr is deep bound. that is why this happens. using angular copy we unhook the binding between these variables.